# Is Stack Exchange having performance/response issues?

Tags: bug, performance

Are there any known performance issues with Stack Exchange (Stack Overflow in particular) right now?

I've noticed over the last several weeks at random times of the day, I get slow responses or timeout from:

- Viewing a post
- Saving a post
- Listing posts by tag
- Listing posts on the home page
- Hovering over the inbox or stats on the title bar
- Posting
- Commenting

And just about every other part of the site I can find.

It's frustrating when you can't open your inbox, or when you post and it just hangs.  Even stranger, sometimes while the animation is still spinning, I can go open the link in a new tab or window and my post is already there. Even though where I posted it is still waiting for a server response.

I've seen this now at at least three different locations on 4 different computers, so I don't think it's just me.  Anyone else noticed sluggishness in the site?  Anything being done about it?

Comment: Yup. Especially with loading the review page.

Comment: I've been noticing that the inbox doesn't like opening